# Android Recyclerview doesn't update unless I scroll

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

So I have a scroll view and I'm loading images from firestore and then giving them to the recycler view. Then I'm getting the images from firebase storage and passing them into the adapater, once they reach I notify the adapter that the item's positoin has changed and that seems to work fine. The thing is that the update only works when I scroll, doesn't update automatically That's my adapter and udpate code

```
val adapter = RvMoviesToDeleteAdapter(tempArrayList)

adapter.setOnClickListener(object: RvMoviesToDeleteAdapter.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(position: Int, movie: Movie) {
        super.onClick(position, movie)
        Log.e("a7a", "called 2")
        openDeleteDialog(movie)
    }
})

binding?.rvMoviesToDelete?.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(requireActivity(), 3)
```

```
private fun updateImage(moviePosition: Int) {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        Log.e("a7a", "called")
        try {
            SharedVars.allMoviesLoaded = movies
            binding?.rvMoviesToDelete?.adapter?.notifyItemChanged(moviePosition)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            handleLoadingErrors("updateImg", "$e")
        }
    }
}
```

I screen recorded my phone so you would better understand what I mean
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z4Kd3-CPbVs5IU-y2eSUekcvYvpBLhyA/view?usp=share_link

I tried `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` and `adapter.notifyItemChanged()`

Comment: Add the code of the adapter.

Comment: @user19514005, can you please add some code from your adapter's `onCreateViewHolder`, `onBindViewHolder` and binder class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`notifyItemChanged` is UI operation and must be triggered from the Main thread.  Try moving your `notifyItemChanged` inside `withContext` like this:

```
try {
    SharedVars.allMoviesLoaded = movies
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        binding?.rvMoviesToDelete?.adapter?.notifyItemChanged(moviePosition)
    }
} catch (e: Exception) {
    handleLoadingErrors("updateImg", "$e")
}
```

This should work.